# Change owner and acl permission recursively

Tags: powershell, acl

Due to the mounting of a partition, I would like to change Owner and ACL permissions (total control in my case) recursively (folders and sub-folders and files) with Powershell.

Comment: Check [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/35300/changing-permissions-with-pwershell-recursive) answer from serverfault that shows how to get and set acls on items recursively.

Answer (score 4):

Got it a very simple way (for what i wanted) even if its depreciated:

```
icacls "e:\program files" /grant administrators:F /t
```

Answer (score 3):

Well for owner I found this way:

```
takeown /f "c:\folder\subfolder" /r
```